# How to make a character table for a group?

Tags: tables, math-mode

Is there a good template for making the [character table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_table) of a finite group in Tex? I'm in pure math so I'd like to use notation fitting that field as opposed to something like chemistry. I'm looking for a template because I want something that is set up in a nice way and shows the name of the group (that is, I'd like to be able to use it for several different groups). Something that generates the table itself would be cool, but mostly I'm just looking for a basic template that displays a table I know already nicely.

Note: Edited based on comments.

Comment: Most people will not know what that is, you may want to link to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_table) but what are you asking? The presentation is normally a trivial `tabular` table, or are you asking to calculate the entries in TeX?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is a "character table " for a "finite group"? Please explain.